# Intended Paragraphs Inside Environment

Tags: environments, indentation

I have decided to come back to beautiful LaTeX typesetting after several years. I have just decided to hone up my LaTeX skills but have found out that it will be not easy.

Here is my question: I have found this code from book class file (World Scientific Publishing), which makes  a numbered framed box.

But this code doesn't allow me to indent paragraphs coming after the 1st paragraph (In the figure below, the second paragraph starts with "Let", which is intended.)  I wonder how I indent paragraphs after the first paragraph like the figure below.[image: Framed Box]

The code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\newcounter{boxcnt}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theboxcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{boxcnt}}
\newenvironment{boxedtxt}[1]{%
  \vskip6pt
  \parindent0pt\leftskip0pt
  \itemindent0pt\leftmargin0pt
  \fboxsep=8pt
  \normalfont
  \refstepcounter{boxcnt}
  \begin{boxedminipage}[0.5pt]{\hsize}
    \selectfont
    {\bfseries{Box\ \theboxcnt\enspace}#1}
    \vskip 6pt plus2pt minus1pt
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{boxedminipage}%
  \vskip6pt\noindent\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedtxt}{Summation and series}
Summation is the operation of addition. The result of summation is called the
sum. The summation operation can be conveniently indicated by the the summation
symbol (the capital sigma, $\sum$). For instance, the sum of the square of the
first four natural numbers can be written as
\[
  \sum_{k=1}^{4}{k^2}= 1 + 2^2+3^2 +4^2 = 30,
\]
where $k=1$ in the subscript and 4 in the superscript denote that the summation
index $k$ takes integer values from 1 to 4.

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{n} = {a_1+a_2+\cdots.+a_n}$ be a sequence of n numbers bla
bla \ldots 
\end{boxedtxt} 
It is noted that the matrix bla bla \ldots 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When I compile your example none of the paragraphs inside the box get indented...

Comment: Don't set \parindent=0pt. Plain TeX sets \parindent=20pt default.  base.sty only uses 0pt and 1em.

Comment: And as a tiny remark: I edited `$$ ... $$` into `\[ ... \]`. You should avoid the first syntactic form to create display math as it is deprecated and non-expacted things might happen.

Comment: Also `\bfseries` does not take an argument. It is a *switch* (i.e. a toggle). So `\bfseries{...} ...` is just the same as `\bfseries ... ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've corrected the code so that it does what you want. However I also propose another similar environment, that I've called  `fboxedtxt`, based on the `framed` package, which has the advantage to break across pages if necessary. Also, if required, it's not too difficult to modify the code to obtain coloured frames and/or shaded environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{boxcnt}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theboxcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{boxcnt}}
\newenvironment{boxedtxt}[1]
       {\vskip6pt
\leftskip0pt
\itemindent0pt\leftmargin0pt
\fboxsep=8pt
\normalfont
\refstepcounter{boxcnt}\noindent
\begin{boxedminipage}[0.5pt]{\hsize}\selectfont{\bfseries{Box\
    \theboxcnt\enspace}#1}\vskip 6pt plus2pt minus1pt
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces\parindent1em}
     {\end{boxedminipage}%
\vskip6pt \noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcounter{fboxcnt}[chapter]
\renewcommand\thefboxcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{fboxcnt}}
\newenvironment{fboxedtxt}[1]
       {
\FrameSep=8pt
\OuterFrameSep=6pt
\FrameRule=1pt
\normalfont
\refstepcounter{fboxcnt}\noindent
\begin{oframed}\noindent\selectfont{\bfseries{Box\
    \theboxcnt\enspace}#1}\vskip 6pt plus2pt minus1pt
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces}
     {\end{oframed}%
\vskip6pt \noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
Some text. Sometext. Some text. Sometext. Some text. Sometext. Some text. Sometext.
\setcounter{chapter}{3}\setcounter{boxcnt}{1}
\begin{boxedtxt}{Summation and series}
  Summation is the operation of addition. The result of summation is called the
  sum. The summation operation can be conveniently indicated by the the summation
  symbol (the capital sigma, $\sum$). For instance, the sum of the square of the
  first four natural numbers can be written as
  \[ \sum_{k=1}^{4}{k^2}= 1 + 2^2+3^2 +4^2 = 30, \]
  where $k=1$ in the subscript and 4 in the superscript denote that the summation
  index $k$ takes integer values from 1 to 4.

  Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{n} = \bigl\{a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\bigr\}$ be a sequence of $ n $ numbers in which each term $a_k$ is given by a certain rule, whose character is here irrelevant. A series is the sum of a sequence and can be written in summation notation as
  \[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} = a_1 + a_2 + \dotsm + a_n\]%
  If the number of terms is finite, the series is called a finite series; otherwise it is called an infinite series. An example of an infinite series is the geometric series
  \[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \dotsm \]%
\end{boxedtxt}
It is noted that the matrix bla bla \ldots
\setcounter{boxcnt}{1}
\begin{fboxedtxt}{Summation and series}
  Summation is the operation of addition. The result of summation is called the
  sum. The summation operation can be conveniently indicated by the the summation
  symbol (the capital sigma, $\sum$). For instance, the sum of the square of the
  first four natural numbers can be written as
  \[ \sum_{k=1}^{4}{k^2}= 1 + 2^2+3^2 +4^2 = 30, \]
  where $k=1$ in the subscript and 4 in the superscript denote that the summation
  index $k$ takes integer values from 1 to 4.

  Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{n} = \bigl\{a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\bigr\}$ be a sequence of $ n $ numbers in which each term $a_k$ is given by a certain rule, whose character is here irrelevant. A series is the sum of a sequence and can be written in summation notation as
  \[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} = a_1 + a_2 + \dotsm + a_n\]%
  If the number of terms is finite, the series is called a finite series; otherwise it is called an infinite series. An example of an infinite series is the geometric series
  \[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \dotsm \]%
\end{fboxedtxt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Summation" isn't indented, though the OP required this.

Comment: ??? I understood the first paragraph after title should not be intended (as is standard in English, by the way). Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I guess you don't misunderstood. I was confused because in the original version of the MWE nothing was indented...

Comment: Nice alternative environment by the way!

Comment: In my code, the first paragraph was not indented (which I wanted) but after the first paragraph, the code doesn't allow me to indent the others. So this property is similar to LaTeX book class: no indentation in the first paragraph in a section, but indentation for paragraphs after it.

Comment: One more question: It is possible not to have a horizontal line after page  break. The box continuing to page 2 has a horizontal line. I prefer not having a horizontal line for the continuation of boxes going to other pages.

Comment: It is possible not to have a horizontal line before and after page break (i.e; at the bottom of a page and at the top of the next page). Please so my updated answer. For that I replaced the `framed` environment with `oframed`. Is that OK?